# How and why Aristotelian essentialism is a problem for Quine?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science, aristotle, modal-logic, quine

I cannot understand how and why the Aristotelian essentialism is problematic for Quine. I have tried to read articles on the theme but probably I am not smart enough to understand them. Could you please explain this issue for me?

Comment: Otherwise, it might help you to study the history of logical positivism before you study Quine. Also, this YouTube video by Hilary Putnam is good, Quine as the reluctant Platonist, why?  The problem of mathematics which is used by science. Quine & Ontology:  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=AhHIVEN839s

Comment: Is there a particular reference from Quine's works that express this problem with Aristotelian essentialism in more detail?

Comment: Existence, SEP scroll down a bit a you will seeAristotle discussed. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/existence/

Comment: On What Exists Mathematically, or
Indispensability without Platonism  Just an article that may interest you at some point. http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/4757/1/NewsteadandFranklinTheMetaphysicsofMathematicsJuly132009a.doc

Comment: It is a problem because Quine is an epistemological holist. For him, any properties of any entities are, in part, artifacts of a theory used to posit them, not something indwelling out there. Which is pretty much an outright rejection of any essences or de re metaphysics, see [SEP Suspicions about Essentialism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/essential-accidental/).